# Stripe.net not opened in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, stripe-payments

I have tried to open Stripe.net source code in Visual Studio 2015, but projects not getting load [Error message](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/23055341/22500755/89915e6a-e86e-11e6-97b6-6dc106e4e7c7.jpg)
I have download the code from [Code Link](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet)
How i can open project code,please help me?

Comment: Have you had a look at the output window of Visual Studio? Wat was reported there?

Comment: i have added the error link while opening the project solution file https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/23055341/22500755/89915e6a-e86e-11e6-97b6-6dc106e4e7c7.jpg